# dnnweaver V2 vivado project

Tags: fpga, vivado

Recently I've been working on a open-source DLA named [dnnweaver](https://github.com/hsharma35/dnnweaver2). But I got some errors when I tried to create a vivado project through the way on [its github resposity](https://github.com/hsharma35/dnnweaver2/tree/master/hardware).

1, the instruction file says "We will also use the DDR1 IP to create a clock for DnnWeaver. To do this, specify 150MHz as the frequency for c0_ddr4_ui_clk by double-clicking the IP and then specifying 150 MHz in the Advanced Clocking tab." But I found that c0_ddr4_ui_clk couldn't be modified.

2, because of the c0_ddr4_ui_clk, I tried to use another clock for dnnweaver module. But I've been getting timing errors.

really need some help...

Comment: I notice that you have not raised an issue about that in GIT. There is an issue about the clock but that has to do with the frequency (which, I admit, also has not been answered for 25 days...)

Comment: actuallly, the issue about clock in github was raised by me.....